# Vertically Center Images/Icons inside percentage-height toolbar

Tags: css, html, cordova, vertical-alignment, statusbar

I am writing a status bar for a PhoneGap application. It needs to look something like this:

```
____________________________________________________________
|[Icon] [Logo]            [Text]               [Icon][Icon]|
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The icons are square images of the same size (50% of bar height, centered vertically), but are of a different height than the logo, which should fill up 100% bar height. The text is the current page title.

The status bar height is a percentage of the total screen height and I cannot use fixed height. My current structure looks like this:

```
<div class="statusbar">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="a.png" class="icon" />
    <img src="logo.png" class="logo" />
  </div>

  <span class="ptitle">Text</span>

  <div class="right">
    <img src="b.png" class="icon" />
    <img src="c.png" class="icon" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` where appropriate but the icon heights (set to 100%) end up filling up the entire screen unless I set them as position: absolute; which then prevents me from being able to put them side-by-side.

How can I place these components as shown (left-center-right) while centering everything vertically?

Comment: what CSS do you have at this time ? (markup is not valid (div|span|div)

Comment: @GCyrillus: can you expand on why the markup is invalid?

Comment: inline-boxe squeezed between two block-boxes, you could either use only <span> or only <p> ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
/* page set up */
html, body { height:100%; margin:0; }

/* diagnostic coloring */
.statusbar { background:#FFC; }

/* status bar height is percentage of screen height  */
.statusbar { height:20%; }

/* icon heights to be 50% of status bar. logo height to be 100% of status bar.
   All vertically centered */
.logo { height:100%; }
.icon { height:50%; }
img { vertical-align: middle; }

/* line box positioning */
.statusbar { text-align:justify; }
.statusbar > div { display:inline-block; height:100%;}
.statusbar:after { content:''; width:100%; display: inline-block;}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAq2E/3/

Comment: hello, to avoid gap from :after , use line height :) http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dlvCp  In this exemple , the higher element will give final height of container.

Comment: @GCyrillus: thank you, your solution is helpful. You should put it here so it can be up-voted :)

Answer (score 1):

as you requested it , here a similar answer (same basic method) , where line-height is used and where height is adjusted to content :

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dlvCp

```
header * {display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:1.2em;
  margin:0 10px;
}
header {
  text-align:justify;
  line-height:0;
  background:#bbb;
  padding:0;  
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;
}
header:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:99%;
  vertical-align:top;

}
```